# Calibri font printed as Arial

Tags: reporting-services, printing, fonts, ssrs-2008

I have a Report that uses the Calibri font. It is rendered fine in IE, however when I print the report (clicking on the Printer icon) the text comes out in Arial.

What can I do to get the report to print using Calibri?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, all I need to do was copy the font over on to the Report Server box and then crucially **restart it**.

Comment: +1 I had to install arial narrow on the server so this helped.